# Convert varchar to date in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

```
function details_klanten($idKlant,$start,$eind){
    $this->db->select(' Project.idProject,
                        Project.Titel, 
                        Project.idProjecttype, 
                        Project.Begindatum, 
                        Project.Deadline, 
                        Project.idKlant,
                        Projecttypes.idProjecttypes,
                        Projecttypes.Type, 
                        Werknemer.idWerknemer,
                        Werknemer.Voornaam,
                        Statusproject.idStatusProject,
                        Statusproject.Soort,
                        Klant.Naam');
    $this->db->order_by('Titel', 'asc');
    $this->db->from('Project');
    $this->db->join('Klant', 'Klant.idKlant = Project.idKlant');
    $this->db->join('Projecttypes', 'Projecttypes.idProjecttypes = Project.idProjecttype');
    $this->db->join('Werknemer', 'Werknemer.idWerknemer = Project.idWerknemer');
    $this->db->join('Statusproject', 'Statusproject.idStatusProject = Project.idStatusProject');
                if ($idKlant > 0){
    $this->db->where('Klant.idKlant',$idKlant);
    $this->db->where('Project.Begindatum >',$start);
    $this->db->where('Project.Deadline <',$eind);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows()>0){
        return $query->result();
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The `project.Begindatum` and the `Project.Deadline` are `varchar(10)`. So it looks at the first two numbers not the full date. For example:

```
$start = '01-04-2014';
'Project.Begindatum' = (Varchar)'02-03-2014'.
```

Then it will be shown because 
it looks only to the `'01'(-04-2014) and the '02'(-03-2014)`

Answer (score 2):

Use mysql's **[STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)** function and also pass third parameter in `where()` as `FALSE`

```
$this->db->where("STR_TO_DATE(Project.Begindatum,'%d-%m-%Y') >",$start,FALSE);
$this->db->where("STR_TO_DATE(Project.Deadline,'%d-%m-%Y') <",$eind,FALSE);
```

Its better to change the type of your columns to store in standard format use `date` type to store dates in database ,Using `STR_TO_DATE` with format `%d-%m-%Y` then the value stored in table should have `%d-%m-%Y` format otherwise it won't work ,it should be compared to `$start = '2014-04-01';`,otherwise you need another function i.e [*DATE_FORMAT*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to format it like `01-04-2014`

```
$this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(Project.Begindatum,'%d-%m-%Y'),'%d-%m-%Y') >",
$start,FALSE);
$this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(Project.Deadline,'%d-%m-%Y'),'%d-%m-%Y') <"
,$eind,FALSE);
```

Comment: This does the same as i had before it still doesnt look to the full date only the first two numbers. (the day)

Comment: It still looks only to the day and not to the full date.

Comment: @Rene: It is doubtful that it is comparing only day of the date part. `str_to_date` with the specified date format string converts the string to a fully qualified date object.

Comment: It only looks to month or the year when it the day equals each other. But i would like to compare the Full date.

Comment: The statement `select str_to_date( ' 02-03-2014', '%d-%m-%Y' );` returns a value `2014-03-02` which is a valid date.

Comment: Perhaps you are comparing without using `str_to_date` function. Use Khalid's solution and you should probably get the results.

Comment: Im using the date_format example of @MKhalidJunaid but it doesnt compare the full date somehow. I just dont get wy not.

Comment: @Rene what exactly you need can you update your question will full details ?

Answer (score 0):

Reminder: `STR_TO_DATE(...)` output format: Y-m-d
Example: 2020-12-24

Therefore: `$start` and `$eind` format: Y-m-d
Example: 2020-12-31

```
$this->db->where("STR_TO_DATE(Project.Begindatum, '%m-%d-%Y') >",$start);
$this->db->where("STR_TO_DATE(Project.Deadline, '%m-%d-%Y') <",$eind);
```

I hope this helps you too. Peace.